# update inner document in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I want to add an array in the document where options.value = 'option 3'.

```
{
  "category":"Lifestyle",
  "title":"Title 2",
  "_id":{
    "$oid":"53fcbe08f29403168bccc6a9"
  },
  "description":"Description 2",
  "postedOn":"Tue Aug 26 22:34:08 IST 2014",
  "options":[
    {
      "id":"ede7c211751e4028513fd876ad744ebc7b1035ed752abaa88f07ad47",
      "value":"option 3"
    },
    {
      "id":"7615718e768bcb1530119a4a02fedfc205bbabfef417047e8388d27c",
      "value":"option 4"
    }
  ]
}
```

please suggest a way to do it in mongo shell.

Comment: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am going to reword your question to ensure I am clear on what you want.

You want to take the document above and modify only the subdocument who's value is equal to "option 3".

I.E. you want to take:

```
{
  "id":"ede7c211751e4028513fd876ad744ebc7b1035ed752abaa88f07ad47",
  "value":"option 3"
},
```

And alter it to something like:

```
{
  "id":"ede7c211751e4028513fd876ad744ebc7b1035ed752abaa88f07ad47",
  "value":"option 3",
  "array":["Value1", "Value2"]
},
```

But you don't want to alter all of subdocuments in the array.

Assuming my interpretation is correct then I think what you want is the Positional Operator:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/

You should be able to do something like:

```
db.collection.update({"options.value":"option 3"}, {$set:{"options.$.array":["Value1","Value2"]}}, false, false)
```